# How can I get a token?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I need to get an access-token so that I can have access to my Firebase Cloud Storage (I specify this in the query:
`"Authorization", "Bearer + token"`).

For this, I have already downloaded Cloud SDK, created a JSON file from Google Console and registered the command:

```
$gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=C:\Project123.json
```

Can you please tell me how to get the access-token from this to paste it in Authorization?

Comment: Okay, I was able to find information in Google. Anyone who encounters a similar problem (you want to extract access-token from any JSON file for any access, then DO NOT need to make login using application-default login, instead you just need to use:
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS =/path/to/service_account_file.json <- here will be your path
and run:
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token.
I hope someone helped. Good luck)

Comment: You should post this comment as an answer (answering your own question is fine)

Answer (score 0):

***Answer by OP:**

*(posted as comment by OP)*

I was able to find information in Google. For anyone who encounters a similar problem:

You want to extract access-token from any JSON file for any access, then DO NOT need to make login using `application-default` login, instead you just need to use:

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS =/path/to/service_account_file.json
```

Then just run:

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

I hope someone helped. Good luck

Comment: Keep in mind that access tokens are only valid for a few minutes.